# LuaLaTeX - Using one font locally

Tags: fonts, luatex

Can I use the font Asana Math only "inside" one macro `\speset` whereas my document uses the Stix Font by default?

No MWE to propose... Sorry.

Comment: you can always make a mwe but `\newfontfamily\am{Asana Math}...\def\speset{...  \am ...}`

Comment: So easy, I add a MWE as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short MWE showing the change of the font locally. **This just uses the comment of David Carlisle.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\am{Asana Math}
\newcommand\speset{\bgroup\am\BbbC\ or \BbbH\egroup}

\begin{document}

C or H

\speset

C or H

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: you probably want a group, currently the rest of the document is in asana math

Comment: My initial test was so bad... This has been corrected.